# How to find a float number in a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, arcpy

I am trying to create a list of points from a road network. Here, I try to put their coordinates in a List of [x,y] whose items have a float format. As a new point from the network is picked, it should be checked with the existing points in the list. if it exists, then the same index will be given to the feature of network, otherwise a new point will be added to the list and the new index will be given to the feature. 
I know that a float number will be saved differently form integers, but for exactly the same float numbers, I still cannot use:

```
If new_point in list_of_points:
   #do something
```

and I should use:

```
for point in list_of_points:
    if abs(point.x-new_point.x)<0.01 and abs(point.y-new_point.y)<0.01
         #do something
```

the points are supposed to be exactly the same as I snap them using the ArcGIS software, and when I check the coordinates in the software they are exactly the same.

I asked this question for:

1- I think using "in" can make my code tidy and also faster while using for-loop is kind of clumsy way of coding for this situation.

2- I want to know: does that mean even exactly the same float numbers are stored differently?

Comment: The `in` operator for sequence types always checks for exact equality -- so you'd need to use some sort of "less-elegant" loop to search for close or approximately equal values (or use a third-party module). You could also implement your own `list`-like container type that defined its own `__contains__` method (which is called to implement `in` operations if it exists).

Comment: I think what I have done so far (apart form creating a List_like class with _contain_ method) is kind of using a less-elegant loop. however, I think using the built-in "in" can increase the performance of my code. right now, I am working with small size of data but dealing with a huge dataset may lead into low-performance code.

Comment: As I said, the _only_ way I see to be able to use the `in` operator would be to define the method in your own container class. Even if done that way, the implementation encapsulated in that class' `__contains__()` method would need to either contain the in-elegant loop or call some function in an external module -- perhaps written in C -- that does what you want as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2):

It's never a good idea to check for equality between two floating point numbers.  However, there are built in functions to do a comparison like that.  From `numpy` you can use `allclose`.  For example,

```
>>> np.allclose( (1.0,2.0), (1.00000001,2.0000001) )
True
```

This checks if the two array like inputs are element-wise equal within a certain tolerance.  You can adjust the relative and absolute tolerances with keyword arguments.

Comment: This function could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Any given Python implenetation should always store a given floating point number in the same, deterministic, non-random way within itself. I do not believe you can take the same floating point number, input it twice, and have it stored in two different ways. But I'm also reluctant to believe that you're going to be getting exact duplicates of coordinates out of a geographic program like ArcGIS, especially if the resolution is very small. There are many ways that floating point math can mess with your expectations, so you shouldn't ever expect that you'll have identical floats. And between different machines and different versions, you get even more possibilities for error.

If you're worried about the elegance of your code, you can just create a function to abstract out the `for` loop.

```
def coord_in(coord, coord_list):
  for other_coord in coord_list:
    if abs(coord.x-other_coord.x)<0.00001 and abs(coord.y-other_coord.y)<0.00001:
      return True
  return False
```

Comment: that's a good explanation. just to add more info, I use Arcpy which is representing the ArcGIS core. I used Snap function to locate all the nodes of intersecting lines on each other hoping they have exactly the same value then, and Arcgis shows the same value for the ones I checked. nevertheless, it seems that there is no other workaround for this situation.

Comment: @msc87 I'm not familiar with Arcpy, but `Snap` sounds an awful lot like a function that will take coordinates that are "almost identical" and place them on the same spot. So it would also be doing an "approximately equal" sort of thing. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For a large number of points, numpy will always be faster (and perhapd more elegant). If you have separated the x and y coords into (float) arrays arrx and arry:

```
numpy.sometrue((arrx-point.x)**2+(arry-point.y)**2<tol**2)
```

will return True if point is within distance tol of an existing point.

Comment: this still needs a for-loop to be implemented to go through the list for checking the distance tolerance.

Comment: If you wish, you can also make the point.x-s and y-s into arrays too, and form a rank-2 distance matrix, seeking the minimum along each column. That would be a one-step operation.

Answer (score 0):

2: exactly the same literal (e.g., "2.3") will be stored as exactly the same float representation for for a given platform and data-type, but in general it depends on the bit-ness, endian-ness and perhaps the compiler used to make python.

To be certain when comparing numbers, you should at least round to the precision of the least precise number, or (better) do the kind of thing you are doing here.

```
>>> 1==1.00000000000000000000000000000000001
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but helped me develop my own solution using list comprehension. Because of course it's not a good idea to compare two floats using `==`. The following returns list of indices of all elements of the input list that are *reasonably* close to the value we're looking for.

```py
def findFloats(listOfFloats, value):
    return [i for i, number in enumerate(listOfFloats)
            if abs(number-value) < 0.00001]
```